# Format a number as a percentage within a concatenated '& string' cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to output something like this: "cat1/cat2 split: 25%/75%" in a cell by concatenating a string, "cat1/cat2 split: " with two cell references containing fractions.

My first and obvious attempt of concatenating by using '&' works, but looks like this: "cat1/cat2 split: 0.25/0.75"

How can I format this to display those values as percentages?

Comment: Have you tried concatenate with &"%" ?

Comment: Wouldn't that just give "0.75%" (inaccurate). I suppose I could just multiply the original cell by 100 and use your suggestion. That would work in this instance, but I wonder if there a more generalized way to format within a concatenated cell. Thanks for your suggestion, though. It will solve my specific issue

Comment: `=TEXT(0.25,"0%")`

Comment: The problem is that the concatenate function will not carry over formatting, so unless you save the number as string with the % sign, it will not carry over.

Comment: I would do something like =CONCATENATE(A2*100,"%, ",B2*100,"%")

Comment: @Slai Good point, that's another way to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
=A1 & TEXT(B1,"00%") & "/" & TEXT(C1,"00%")
```

where **A1** contains the text and **B1** and **C1** contain the fractions

Comment: I also noted that the pure text part (your A1) can just directly be a string in double quotes.